# Not sure how to solve a problem from online course

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, statics

[image]
I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I don't know the magnitude of F1 or F2 and I'm not sure how to get it from F. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1):

You have two forces, which you can reduce to a single point like this for simplicity given that you do not forget the couple moment. For now, let's assume we only have the two forces.

[image]

Now, we know that the sum of these two vectors gives us the resultant:

$$\vec{\mathbf{F}}_1+\vec{\mathbf{F}}_2 = \vec{\mathbf{F}}$$

No we resolve the force into components and we get

$$F_1\cos(45^\circ)-F_2\sin(30^\circ)=10\\F_1\sin(45^\circ)+F_2\cos(30^\circ)=0$$

Solving these two equations gives us the following results

$$F_1\approx8.965\,\text{N} \\ F_2\approx-7.321\,\text{N}$$

Now you form the vectors from the resultants. Make sure you maintain consistency with the signs (+,-) you use on the component resolutions.

$$ \vec{\mathbf{F}}_1 = 8.965\cos(45^\circ)\hat{\mathbf{i}} + 8.965\cos(45^\circ)\hat{\mathbf{j}} \approx 6.339\hat{\mathbf{i}}+6.339\hat{\mathbf{j}} \\ \vec{\mathbf{F}}_2 = 7.321\sin(30^\circ)\hat{\mathbf{i}} - 7.321\cos(30^\circ)\hat{\mathbf{j}} \approx 3.660\hat{\mathbf{i}}-6.339\hat{\mathbf{j}}$$

To compute the moment you need the position vectors as well. Consider the following.

[image]

Now all you need is to come up with the position vectors

$$\vec{\mathbf{r}}_1 = 2\hat{\mathbf{j}} \\ \vec{\mathbf{r}}_2 = 4\hat{\mathbf{i}} $$

The moment is simply the sum of moments

$$\vec{\mathbf{M}} = \vec{\mathbf{r}}_1\times\vec{\mathbf{F}}_1 + \vec{\mathbf{r}}_2\times\vec{\mathbf{F}}_2 = 18.039\hat{\mathbf{k}}$$

Therefore the couple moment is $M=18.039\,\text{N m}$.